# why is GroupJoin not left outer join?

Tags: c#, linq

> The GroupJoin method has no direct equivalent in relational database
>   terms, but it implements a superset of inner joins and left outer
>   joins. A left outer join is a join that returns each element of the
>   first (left) data source, even if it has no correlated elements in the
>   other data source.

I think the GroupJoin is a equivalent of left join. Because all element of outer will be returned with a collection of matched items in inner. if no matched item is found in inner, an empty collection will be paired with the element in outer.

But why does [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397908%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) say that?

I have read source code of GroupJoin and Join. MarcinJuraszek supply a example. but I think we can use following code.

```
Users.GroupJoin(Cars,user=>id,Car=>userId,(user,cars)=>
if(cars.count==0)
{
//John -- NULL
}
else
{
//Ted  -- [ 2, 3 ]
}
return result;
);
```

original logic for GroupJoin:

```
Lookup<TKey, TInner> lookup = Lookup<TKey, TInner>.CreateForJoin(inner, innerKeySelector, comparer);
foreach (TOuter current in outer)
{
    yield return resultSelector(current, lookup[outerKeySelector(current)]);
}
```

we can also rewrite a LeftJoin:

```
Lookup<TKey, TInner> lookup = Lookup<TKey, TInner>.CreateForJoin(inner, innerKeySelector, 
foreach (TOuter current in outer)
{
    yield return resultSelector(current, lookup[outerKeySelector(current)].DefaultIfEmpty());
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider following situation:

```
TableA - Users

id -- name
1  -- Tom
2  -- John
3  -- Ted

TableB - Cars

id -- userId
1  -- 1
2  -- 3
3  -- 3
```

Standard `LEFT JOIN` for user name and car id would return:

```
name -- carId
Tom  -- 1
John -- NULL
Ted  -- 2
Ted  -- 3
```

Using `GroupJoin` you'll get:

```
name -- carId
Tom  -- [ 1 ]
John -- [ ]
Ted  -- [ 2, 3 ]
```

See the difference?

In SQL the left side idem is shown as many times as many right items matching `JOIN`condition exist.

On `GroupJoin` you'll get left side item once and a collection of right side items matching `JOIN`condition.

Comment: I know the result. I have read the source code of GroupJoin. I'll add some info to question.

Comment: If you know the result of `GroupJoin` you should already see that it's not exactly the same as standard sql join query results ...

Answer (score 1):

I would add a comment, but my rep isnt high enough to do that yet.

Marcin is correct, the simple answer to your question is;
Yes, you COULD make a Left Outer Join return results in the same way that `GroupJoin` does, but why?

`GroupJoin` does a Left Outer Join and then GROUPS the results. A Left Outer Join would simply return a list (as per Marcin's example) without doing any grouping, which you can do if you really want to, but (for whatever reason) you might not want to.

EDIT: Spelling

Comment: thanks. I just want to make sure GroupJoin can do what left join do.